# Can the concussion of a .50 calibre bullet from a sniper shot kill you even if the bullet misses?

Tags: physics, guns

I've heard before that if a sniper shot a .50 calibre bullet at you from a great distance and missed, but the bullet went past your head, that the concussion from the bullet flying by could still kill you, "*literally take your head off*" were the words my source used. My source was the son of a contract defence worker at the Tonapah Airforce base (Area 51) who also happened to be an independent arms dealer in Nevada, so I typically trust his knowledge about weapons, but is there any truth to this?